# Consider the subspaces U = span{2 + x, 1 − x^2}, and W = span{−1 + x + x^2 , −x + x^2} of P2(R). Find U ∩ W

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question:

**Consider the subspaces U = span{2 + x, 1 − x^2}, 
and W = span{−1 + x + x^2, −x + x^2} of
P2(R).**

**a) Find U ∩ W:**

Theres no examples in my textbook of how to solve any of this so I have no clue what I'm doing. By reading around heres what I have so far:

*Let a,b,c,d ∈ R.*
a(2 + x) + b(1 − x^2) = c(−1 + x + x^2) + d(−x + x^2)

*we can simplify this to be:*

(-b)x^2 + (a)x + (2a+b) = (c+d)x^2 + (c-d)x + (-c)

*we can see that:*
-b = c + d,
a = c - d,
2a + b = -c

*I eventually found b,c,d in terms of a:*

b = -5a,
c = 3a,
d = 2a

What do I do now? How do I show U ∩ W?

Comment: you just say a(2+x) + b(1-x^2) = a(2+x) -5a (1-x^2) = a(5x^2 +x -3) any expression of this form is a member of the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computation is correct, i.e. $b = -5a, c = 3a, d = 2a$ holds, then you simply insert the result in the description of $U$ or $W$. That is, using the description of $U$, the intersection $U \cap W$ can be expressed as the set
$$ \{ a(2 + x) + -5a(1 − x^2) | a \in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ a(5x^2 + x - 3) | a \in \mathbb{R} \} $$
or, equivalently, using the description of $W$
$$ \{ c(−1 + x + x^2) + d(−x + x^2) \} = \{ 3a(−1 + x + x^2) + 2a(−x + x^2) | a \in \mathbb{R} \} $$
which is again the same descrption as the one given above, i.e.
$$ \{ a (5x^2 + x - 3 ) | a \in \mathbb{R} \}  \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that any element in $U∩W$ if and only if is of form $5ax^2+ax-3a$. You could conclude that $U∩W=\{5ax^2+ax-3a:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$